# Как сделать чтобы тег a и тег span встали по центру каждый в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы тег a и тег span встали по центру каждый в мобильной версии.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="logo">                      
                    <a href="http://adelfi.kz/">
                        <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo_new-300x212.png">
                    </a>
                    <span>АДЕЛЬФИ<br><p>LUXURY FURNITURE</p></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
.top_text p{    
    text-align: center;
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что, из 4 ответов ни один не подошел?

Answer (score 1):

Что бы  стал по центру, можно сделать его блочным и выровнять

```
a{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Не работает так. Я же делю блок на три под блока, может это причина?

Comment: Если ты поставишь ссылке тип: блок, то она будет блоком, и будет выравниваться по центру при margin:0 autp;

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам надо выровнять по центру картинку?))
1. для тега a - display:block; text-align:center; width:100%;
2. для ВЛОЖЕННОГО img - display:block; margin:0 auto;
3. для тега span - display:block; text-align:center; width:100%;
ну а дальше у вас каша, так как тег p внутрь span несемантично
кроме того, у вас скорее всего применяются еще какие-то дополнительные правила, особенно касается тега p судя по рисунку, есть отступы.

Answer (score 0):

Примените следующие стили:

```css
<style>@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
.logo a{    
    text-align: center
}
.logo img{    
    display:none
}
}
</style>
```

и следующий код ХТМЛ:

```html
<div class="logo">                      
<a href="http://adelfi.kz/"><img src="img/logo_new-300x212.png" alt="Brand" /><p><span>АДЕЛЬФИ LUXURY FURNITURE</span></p></a>
</div>
```

Указание элемента p внутри span вызывает ошибку валидации. И роль span не понятна из предложенного кода. Если этот элемент не важен, то лучше устранить его их кода.

Answer (score -2):

```
.logo { text-align: center; }
```

Так же, внутрь `<span>` нельзя вставлять блочный элемент `<p>`